Malaysia 90-day stamp but with return date written on top
I have a short question. When I entered Malaysia I was given a 90-day stamp but my return ticket was for 1 month. The officer didn't really say anything regarding that, but he did write down the return date on top of the 90-day stamp.
So my question is, would it be okay for me to change the return ticket closer to the 90 days and just explain to them later that I originally intended to stay for 1 month but then decided to stay longer? Because I know they had a 1-month stamp but instead he stamped 90 days for me. I hope you can help me with this question.

What is your citizenship?

Note that your citizenship is important: nationals of some countries normally get 90 days, while others only get 30. I imagine it could be possible for some reason the officer did not have the 30-day stamp available so used the 90-day and added that annotation instead, or that they used the wrong stamp by error (and then realised and added the date). If you are from a country for which only 30 days are allowed, certainly don't rely on the 90 day stamp.

Just to be clear, the return date is 30 days (as it seems you were expecting given your one month return ticket) but the stamp is 90 days? What did the IO say at the time when you asked them about it?
